# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I'm having difficulties with this exercise of calculus

Let $f:(-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)| \leq 2$ for every $x \in (-1, 1)$. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of $(0, 1)$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges, show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ converges.

I'm sorry for my lack of effort but I really don't know where to start here. I don't know what I should make of all the information that is given in the above problem. Why does the fact that the derivative is bounded and that $f(0)=0$ is important in this problem?

Comment: $f(0)=0$ is necessary so that the terms of the series you are trying to show is convergent tend to $0$. Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ is important because otherwise the sequence $x_n = 0$ wouldn't give a finite $\sum_n f(x_n)$. The derivative is bounded because  otherwise the sequence $x_n = \frac1{n^2}$, which has a finite sum, together with the function $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, would give an infinite $\sum_n f(x_n)$.

Comment: Hint: The mean value theorem will give you $|f(x_n)|\le 2x_n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for your help. I can see now how this exercise is related to the MVT but I'm having some difficulties setting it up appropriately. The fact that the argument of the function is a sequence confuses me. Can someone help me with that? Also, since $|f(x_n)|\le 2x_n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(x_n)| \leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ but because the series on the right converges by assumption, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ must also converges. Is that the correct conclusion?

Comment: @Elix: No, the argument to the function is a _single number_, and you're simply applying it to each number in the sequence separately. But it looks like you have the right reasoning otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mean value theorem as proposed by  **Henning Makholm**, one has

$$\frac{\left|f(x_n) - f(0)\right|}{\left|x_n - 0\right|} = \left|\frac{f(x_n) - f(0)}{x_n - 0}\right| = |f'(x)| \leq 2.$$

It follows that

$$|f(x_n)| \leq 2|x_n|.$$

Since $x_n \in (0, 1)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can remove the absolute value on the RHS so that

$$|f(x_n)| \leq 2 x_n.$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(x_n)| \leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$$

and because the series on the right converges by assumption, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$
must also converges by the comparison test.

---

Can someone verify if my work is correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me +1.