# Showing that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(\frac 1n)$ converges using the MVT

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulties with this exercise of calculus:

Let $f:(-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)| \leq \sqrt[3]{|x|}$ for every $x \in (-1, 1)$. Show that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(\frac 1n)$ converges.

This exercise is similar to a question I asked a few days ago (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923236/show-that-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-fx-n-converges)). The solution is related to the MVT but I can't get it to work properly in this case.

Here's what I have done so far:

By the MVT we have

$$\frac{\left|f(\frac 1n) - f(0)\right|}{\left|\frac 1n - 0\right|} = \left|\frac{f(\frac 1n) - f(0)}{\frac 1n - 0}\right| = |f'(x)| \leq \sqrt[3]{|x|}.$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |f(\frac 1n)| \leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\sqrt[3]{|x|} \over n}.$$

I don't know if my work is correct. If it is, how do I show that the RHS series converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't the same $x$ every time. For each $n$ there is a point $x_n \in (0,\frac 1n)$ satisfying $$\frac{|f(\frac 1n) - f(0)|}{|\frac 1n - 0|} = |f'(x_n)| \le  \sqrt[3]{x_n}.$$

Use the fact that $x_n \le \frac 1n$ to conclude $$|f(\frac 1n)| \le \dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{\frac 1n}}{n} = \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}.$$

Now add them up.